# Не работает Burger Bootstrap 4, не открывается

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container header-container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#my-nav" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="my-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
        <div id="my-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto navbar__text">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">How it works</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Instructions</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accounts</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Platforms</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-group__button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">
                    EN
                    <img src="img/arrow.language.svg" class="button__image-arrow" alt="arrow language">
                  </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm-end">
              <li><button class="dropdown-item btn-group__button-info" type="button">RU</button></li>
              <li><button class="dropdown-item btn-group__button-info" type="button">UA</button></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="header__nav-button">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Sign in for free</a>
          </div>


        </div>
      </nav>



      <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: для этого я прикрепил картинку.

Comment: в чем угодно может быть, кнопка вообще нажимается? она может быть перекрыта другим элементом сверху. В консоле ошибки есть? Без кода можно только гадать

Comment: а каким способом мне предоставить вам код?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: внёс изменения. таким образом?

Comment: Ну как минимум у Вашего `div` два атрибута ID, `id="my-nav"` и в самом конце еще на нем висит `id="navbarContent"`.

Comment: @Simon, это в данном случае на работу модалки не влияет - проблема в префиксе -bs-

Comment: не понял, что с bs делать?

Comment: @user483434 ответ на вопрос посмотрите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы подключаете 5-й Бутстрап, а код модального окна используете от 4-го. Между тем одним из важных изменений в 5-м Бустрапе стало добавление префикса `-bs-` в data-атрибуты (data-bs-target, data-bs-toggle) - без него теперь модальные окна, табы и т.д. не работают:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>    
    
    <header class="header">
      <div class="container header-container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-target="#my-nav" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="my-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div id="my-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto navbar__text">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">How it works</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Instructions</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accounts</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Platforms</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-group__button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">
                EN
                <img src="img/arrow.language.svg" class="button__image-arrow" alt="arrow language">
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm-end">
                <li><button class="dropdown-item btn-group__button-info" type="button">RU</button></li>
                <li><button class="dropdown-item btn-group__button-info" type="button">UA</button></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="header__nav-button">
              <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Sign in for free</a>
          </div> 


          </div>
          </nav></div></header>
```